# Colourful notes - todo list annotations in tables

Tags: tables, notes, todonotes

I've decided that I'm going to make LaTeX notes for all of my lectures next year (I'm doing computer science at university). I want a way to brighten my notes up - make them more exiting to read when I'm deep into a month of non-stop revision. My plan was to have a colour scheme for extra reading, important, exam information, connections to other topics, revision strategies, etc...

I was thinking of hight-lighting part of the text, but also to have annotations with the [`todonotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) package, so I can differentiate between course content and commentary.

The problem with this is that `todonotes` annotations doesn't work in tables, the lines from the annotations don't go to the text, and they mess up on some other non-block-text layouts. I suppose its not really designed for them to be left in published work.

Does anyone have a way to annotating that does work in these situations?
Is there a better way I could go about it?
Do you have any tips to produce exciting notes?

EDIT: Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, textwidth=3.5cm]{todonotes}

\newcommand{\summarynote}[1]{\todo[color=yellow!30,size=\small,bordercolor=yellow]{#1}}

\begin{document}
This text has an annotation that works \summarynote{Which is me}\\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Calories (kcal)}\\
\hline
Banana & 95.0\\
\hline
Grapes & 61.5\\
\hline
Kiwi & 49.0 %\summarynote{This sidenote does not work}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

When the second `\summarynote` is uncommented, it give the error message
`LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

Comment: Please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)!

Comment: Honestly, this look like a bug in `todonotes` to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix is to use `inline` notes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
yadda & yadda & boo \\ 
\hline 
ene & mene & muh \\ 
\hline 
gibberish & \begin{minipage}{3cm}see my note\todo[inline]{Fill those cells!}\end{minipage} & more gibberish \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can force the content of the cell you need to attach the note to into a `minipage` and then use the note with the `inline` option. This is the only way I can think of right now, which could make 'regular' notes work decently. Changing the column type to `p` doesn't help.

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: You can make a newcommand for this, like `\newcommand{\tabletodo}[3][]{\begin{minipage}{#2}\todo[inline,#1]{#3}\end{minipage}}`. Credit to the author of the package.